# XSLT to remove instances of element in XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an XML to which i need to apply a XSL to transform it to another XML with different schema version.
The two versions of schema is V1 and V2. In my schema version V1 the maximum instances allowed for ID was 
2 but in version 2 of schema it was changed to 3. Now i am downgrading an XML which is in version 2 to an
XML in version 1, so I want to keep only 2 instances of ID type in my final XML. 
Will appreciate if anyone can let me know how can we do that in XSLT.

In put XML

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <soapenv:Body>
      <tns:send xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/Service/v3">
         <NS2:Message release="006" version="010" xmlns:NS2="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT">

            <NS2:Body>
               <NS2:New>
                  <NS2:Pharmacy>
                     <NS2:Identification>
                        <NS2:ID>
                           <NS2:IDValue>01017</NS2:IDValue>
                           <NS2:IDQualifier>94</NS2:IDQualifier>
                           <NS2:IDRegion>SCA</NS2:IDRegion>
                            <NS2:IDState>CA</NS2:IDState>
                        </NS2:ID>
                        <NS2:ID>
                           <NS2:IDValue>01018</NS2:IDValue>
                           <NS2:IDQualifier>95</NS2:IDQualifier>
                           <NS2:IDRegion>SCA</NS2:IDRegion>
                            <NS2:IDState>CA</NS2:IDState>
                        </NS2:ID>
                        <NS2:ID>
                           <NS2:IDValue>01019</NS2:IDValue>
                           <NS2:IDQualifier>96</NS2:IDQualifier>
                           <NS2:IDRegion>SCA</NS2:IDRegion>
                            <NS2:IDState>CA</NS2:IDState>
                        </NS2:ID>
                             </NS2:Identification>
                             </NS2:Pharmacy>
                    </NS2:New>
            </NS2:Body>
         </NS2:Message>
      </tns:send>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

XSLT :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/Service/v3"
    xmlns:NS2="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|comment()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tns:*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="http://www.test.com/Service/v1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>      
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired Output:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tns:send xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/Service/v1">
         <NS2:Message xmlns:NS2="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT" release="006" version="010">
            <NS2:Body>
               <NS2:New>
                  <NS2:Pharmacy>
                     <NS2:Identification>
                        <NS2:ID>
                           <NS2:IDValue>01017</NS2:IDValue>
                           <NS2:IDQualifier>94</NS2:IDQualifier>
                           <NS2:IDRegion>SCA</NS2:IDRegion>
                           <NS2:IDState>CA</NS2:IDState>
                        </NS2:ID>
                        <NS2:ID>
                           <NS2:IDValue>01018</NS2:IDValue>
                           <NS2:IDQualifier>95</NS2:IDQualifier>
                           <NS2:IDRegion>SCA</NS2:IDRegion>
                            <NS2:IDState>CA</NS2:IDState>
                        </NS2:ID>
                            </NS2:Identification>
                             </NS2:Pharmacy>
                    </NS2:New>
                     </NS2:Identification>
                  </NS2:Pharmacy>
               </NS2:New>
            </NS2:Body>
         </NS2:Message>
      </tns:send>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Second variation which i expect after applying XSLT is to trim a string. The ID instance has IDRegion as 3 characters, i want to trim it to 2 characters "SC" after the XSLT is applied.

So output something like

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <soapenv:Body>
          <tns:send xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/Service/v1">
             <NS2:Message xmlns:NS2="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT" release="006" version="010">
                <NS2:Body>
                   <NS2:New>
                      <NS2:Pharmacy>
                         <NS2:Identification>
                            <NS2:ID>
                               <NS2:IDValue>01017</NS2:IDValue>
                               <NS2:IDQualifier>94</NS2:IDQualifier>
                               <NS2:IDRegion>SC</NS2:IDRegion>
                               <NS2:IDState>CA</NS2:IDState>
                            </NS2:ID>
                            <NS2:ID>
                               <NS2:IDValue>01018</NS2:IDValue>
                               <NS2:IDQualifier>95</NS2:IDQualifier>
                               <NS2:IDRegion>SC</NS2:IDRegion>
                                <NS2:IDState>CA</NS2:IDState>
                            </NS2:ID>
                                </NS2:Identification>
                                 </NS2:Pharmacy>
                        </NS2:New>
                         </NS2:Identification>
                      </NS2:Pharmacy>
                   </NS2:New>
                </NS2:Body>
             </NS2:Message>
          </tns:send>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation (both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:NS2="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="NS2:ID[position() > 2]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <tns:send xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/Service/v3">
            <NS2:Message release="006" version="010"
            xmlns:NS2="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT">
                <NS2:Body>
                    <NS2:New>
                        <NS2:Pharmacy>
                            <NS2:Identification>
                                <NS2:ID>
                                    <NS2:IDValue>01017</NS2:IDValue>
                                    <NS2:IDQualifier>94</NS2:IDQualifier>
                                    <NS2:IDRegion>SCA</NS2:IDRegion>
                                    <NS2:IDState>CA</NS2:IDState>
                                </NS2:ID>
                                <NS2:ID>
                                    <NS2:IDValue>01018</NS2:IDValue>
                                    <NS2:IDQualifier>95</NS2:IDQualifier>
                                    <NS2:IDRegion>SCA</NS2:IDRegion>
                                    <NS2:IDState>CA</NS2:IDState>
                                </NS2:ID>
                                <NS2:ID>
                                    <NS2:IDValue>01019</NS2:IDValue>
                                    <NS2:IDQualifier>96</NS2:IDQualifier>
                                    <NS2:IDRegion>SCA</NS2:IDRegion>
                                    <NS2:IDState>CA</NS2:IDState>
                                </NS2:ID>
                            </NS2:Identification>
                        </NS2:Pharmacy>
                    </NS2:New>
                </NS2:Body>
            </NS2:Message>
        </tns:send>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tns:send xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/Service/v3">
         <NS2:Message xmlns:NS2="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT" release="006" version="010">
            <NS2:Body>
               <NS2:New>
                  <NS2:Pharmacy>
                     <NS2:Identification>
                        <NS2:ID>
                           <NS2:IDValue>01017</NS2:IDValue>
                           <NS2:IDQualifier>94</NS2:IDQualifier>
                           <NS2:IDRegion>SCA</NS2:IDRegion>
                           <NS2:IDState>CA</NS2:IDState>
                        </NS2:ID>
                        <NS2:ID>
                           <NS2:IDValue>01018</NS2:IDValue>
                           <NS2:IDQualifier>95</NS2:IDQualifier>
                           <NS2:IDRegion>SCA</NS2:IDRegion>
                           <NS2:IDState>CA</NS2:IDState>
                        </NS2:ID>
                     </NS2:Identification>
                  </NS2:Pharmacy>
               </NS2:New>
            </NS2:Body>
         </NS2:Message>
      </tns:send>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use and overriding of the **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.

**UPDATE**:

In a comment the OP has added a new requirement: each `NS2:IDRegion` has to be truncated to two characters.

**Here is the updated transformation that implements the new requirement:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
 xmlns:NS2="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="NS2:IDRegion/text()">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,2)"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="NS2:ID[position() > 2]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tns:send xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/Service/v3">
         <NS2:Message xmlns:NS2="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT" release="006" version="010">
            <NS2:Body>
               <NS2:New>
                  <NS2:Pharmacy>
                     <NS2:Identification>
                        <NS2:ID>
                           <NS2:IDValue>01017</NS2:IDValue>
                           <NS2:IDQualifier>94</NS2:IDQualifier>
                           <NS2:IDRegion>SC</NS2:IDRegion>
                           <NS2:IDState>CA</NS2:IDState>
                        </NS2:ID>
                        <NS2:ID>
                           <NS2:IDValue>01018</NS2:IDValue>
                           <NS2:IDQualifier>95</NS2:IDQualifier>
                           <NS2:IDRegion>SC</NS2:IDRegion>
                           <NS2:IDState>CA</NS2:IDState>
                        </NS2:ID>
                     </NS2:Identification>
                  </NS2:Pharmacy>
               </NS2:New>
            </NS2:Body>
         </NS2:Message>
      </tns:send>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is what i was looking for. However i have one more question, how do we truncate the length of a string. for example in the ID element, NS2:IDRegion was initially 2 characters in Version 2 and in Version 3 it was increased to 3 Characters. So when i downgrade from V3 to V1 , i would like to truncate the length to 2 characters, so if i get SCA it becomes SC.

Comment: @Guest, I am glad that my answer was useful to you. Could you, please, *accept* this answer (by clicking the check-mark next to it)? As for your new question, please, ask it as ... a new SO question -- it isn't readable to exchange code as comments and also it wouldn't be visible and useful to our readers.

Comment: I have edited the question and have put the expected transformation for string truncation. Will really appreciate if you can help.

Comment: @Guest, See my updated answer. Please, when you have new questions, ask them as separate, new questions.